How to limit concurrent pipeline job execution on an Azure agent?
EDIT: It turns out I was experiencing rapid failures from an instances that still had a docker container running from the previous runs. It looked as though a parallel problem to me when it was in fact a dirty environment. My initial question is misleading in that it implies multiple jobs are run on agents. I no longer believe this to be the case.
I have the following needs in developing a pipeline on Azure Devops with our own instances running as agents:

I need stages to execute concurrently
Each stage needs to be guaranteed to execute on its own agent

I have #1 going. The problem is that I am running into resource and port contentions. I am outputting the build ID on stage runs and they often report the same agent:
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Debug
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "Agent ID: $(Agent.Id)"

How do I make sure that each agent only runs one stage and/or job at a time?

Your question is confusing and contains contradictory statements: I need stages to execute concurrently vs How do I make sure that each agent only runs one stage and/or job at a time?. Maybe consider editing your question and rephrase some sentences? Also, it might help if you explain your use case or scenario.

@RuiJarimba I can't have multiple stages running on one machine at a time. I am running a docker container that needs to bind to a specific port and stages fail randomly because of the port conflict when they are run on the same machine at the same time. I also suspect that I am running out of memory, which is why I said resource and port conflicts.

You mean different stages in the same build? Or the same stage (e.g. Build) running on concurrent builds?

@RuiJarimba Both. I only want one job/stage at a time to run on an agent. No machine should be executing two jobs at the same time regardless of where they are from.

Hi @eltiare, May I know if you have got a chance to go through the suggestions below in this post? Will it be a workaround for you to explicitly demand to use different agents by their names? Hope the answers may resolve your query in this post. Thx.

Hi @eltiare, At your convenience, can you please let us know the latest status of this issue? Does either of the suggestions work for you? Your time is much appreciated.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Neither solution worked as my understanding of the problem was flawed. I have posted an answer with my solution.

My problem was that a docker container was being run manually in the pipeline. Since the machines persist, the container continued to run on the next pipeline. This caused port and name conflicts.
The solution is to manually stop the container at the end of the pipeline and set the step to always run regardless of failure of previous steps. I also defensively set a step that stops and removes the container if necessary before starting up the container.

Consider using an exclusive lock:

The exclusive lock check allows only a single run from the pipeline to proceed. All stages in all runs of that pipeline that use the resource are paused. When the stage using the lock completes, then another stage can proceed to use the resource. Also, only one stage is allowed to continue.

Set on a stage:
stages:
- stage: A
  lockBehavior: sequential
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    steps:
    - script: Hey!

Set on the pipeline:
lockBehavior: runLatest
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    steps:
    - script: Hey!

Related:

Azure DevOps Pipeline lockbehavior in simple build pipeline (no deployment/release)
Exclusive Lock Pipeline Level - Azure
Azure pipeline: exclusive lock sequential not locking jobs from other runs


Thanks for the lead. I have since realized my mistake and updated the question.

@eltiare maybe you should create a new question regarding your Docker problem? You can still use an exclusive lock as I suggested to ensure a pipeline or stage runs at a time. Consider adding some cleanup tasks at the beginning and/or end of the stage(s) to ensure containers are properly terminated.

That's precisely what I did. The container was run manually and I had to add a later step to stop the container. I also added some defensive code to stop and remove the container if one was left over from a previous run.

@eltiare so problem is finally solved? :-)

Per youR requirement/query on

How to limit concurrent pipeline job execution on one Azure agent?

How do I make sure that each agent only runs one stage and/or job at a time?


Let's assume you have a pipeline with two stages and each stage has defined one agent job to use the same self-hosted agent pool; and this pool was added 2 container agents.
To configure the two stages run in parallel, we can add dependsOn: [] property for each stage. And when we have such self-hosted parallel jobs as below by the time we trigger this pipeline,

Sufficient - at least 2;
Idle - not consumed or say occupied by other pipeline agent jobs;

By default, the agent jobs in the two stages should be able to pick up 2 different agents in that self-hosted agent pool at the same time, so as to run the agent jobs simultaneously.
However, this may not be reliable when there is only 1 parallel job that is idle or released. For this, you may try to explicitly demand the two agents jobs running on different agents in the same agent pool by specifying for example different agent names. Here is a sample for your reference.
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    pool: 
      name: TestPool
      demands:
        Agent.Name -equals Agent1
    steps:
    - script: echo Hey! This is job A1 in stage A running on Agent1.

- stage: B
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    pool: 
      name: TestPool
      demands:
        Agent.Name -equals Agent2
    steps:
    - script: echo Hey! This is job B1 in stage B running on Agent2

